# Windows does not recognize my keyboard

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard

I use a Blackweb gaming keyboard and whenever I boot into Windows, it doesn't work. When I go to the "Devices" section in Settings, I see "Driver error".

I've tried going into Device Manager to disable and re-enable it and it begins to work after a few tries until I reboot the system and it's back to scratch again.

Is there a way to assign keyboard drivers to a particular USB port permanently so that whenever I plug in, it just works? I'm super desperate at this point

Comment: Do other keyboards work? Did your "Blackweb" keyboard come with specific driver? https://www.reddit.com/r/keyboards/comments/6nhejg/blackweb_gaming_software_verison_11_blackweb/ ???

Answer (score 0):

Blackweb doesn't have a website for downloading drivers.

You should have received a Windows driver on a CD with your keyboard.

A community service website has accumulated some Blackweb drivers:
[Blackweb Drivers - JSE's Blog](https://jsebean.com/blackweb),
which you could try.